# iRobot Create 2 Flash CRC message

Tags: mobile-robot, irobot-create, roomba

In testing my iRobot Create 2, I discovered that the following message is being sent periodically over the serial interface: "    **Flash CRC successful: 0x0 (0x0)**". Is this expected behavior or am I making an error in the way I'm connecting? I could not find this message documented anywhere.

**To reproduce this**: iRobot Create 2 connected to a Windows 10 PC via the USB-Serial cable. Connecting via Putty at 115200 baud. Type ctrl-G to reboot the robot. I'll see the normal reboot message, then after a few minutes, the robot sends the above Flash CRC message.

Comment: This is very strange, but I didn't post the previous question that @jsotola mentioned. It appears that someone quoted me and pasted an image of my post in their comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Create 2 displays all kinds of internal debugging messages in plain text when it is not in an open interface mode. (For a less obtuse one, try putting it on the dock while you are connected to the serial port!) These will go away once you enter OI mode (op code 128).

Please note that I am an iRobot employee, but the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.

Comment: I am receiving these messages occasionally even in OI mode :(